# Change string char at index X

Tags: string, bash, unix

I'm searched for a long time how to do a simple string manipulation in `UNIX`

I have this string:

```
theStr='...............'
```

And I need to change the 5th char to A, How can it be done?

In `C#` it's done like this `theStr[4] = 'A'; // Zero based index.`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can achieve this with `sed`, the stream line editor:

`echo $theStr | sed s/./A/5`

First you pipe the output of $theStr to sed, which replaces the fifth character with A.

Comment: +1. Indeed sed is the right tool. On a side note, this particular version will only work if the input string consists of '.'

Comment: No, actually, the `.` doesn't represent the character "dot", but it's a match to all character. If I wanted to match the dot, it would write `\.`

Comment: hah, didn't realize that at all when I wrote that.
This is perfect !

Comment: What if the file is 8gb in size and I need to replace three characters at position 4932, 4933, 4934 ?

Comment: @alete cat file | sed s/./A/4932 |  sed s/./A/4933 and for the other offsets too, my guess would be, that set can accept a list of Positions, but i can't make it work

Answer (score 19):

```
a="............"
b="${a:0:4}A${a:5}"
echo ${b}
```

Here is one really good [tutorial](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) on string manipulation.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's elegant, or which version of bash you need, but

```
theStr="${theStr:0:4}A${theStr:5}"
```

The first part returns first four characters, then the character 'A', and then all the characters starting with the 6th one