# How to replace the first k characters of a string?

Tags: linux, bash

I know how to replace a certain substring of a given string:

```
foo=abcABC
echo ${foo/abc/xyz}       # xyzABC
```

Is it also possible to replace the first k characters by k times a given character?

**Update**: Example:
`foobar`, replace first `k = 3` characters by `Z` yields `ZZZbar`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input & output you're looking for?

Comment: Sure, example has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Change string char at index X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9318094/1983854). Given the string `$foo`, to change the first `k` characters by a string `$pattern`, this can make it:

```
for ((i=0; i < $k; i++))
do
  foo="${foo:0:$i}$pattern${foo:$((i+1))}"
done
```

#### Test

```
$ a="hellomynameisyou"
$ k=5
$ pattern="x"
$ for ((i=0; i < $k; i++)); do a="${a:0:$i}$pattern${a:$((i+1))}"; echo $a; done
xellomynameisyou
xxllomynameisyou
xxxlomynameisyou
xxxxomynameisyou
xxxxxmynameisyou
```

#### For your specific example

```
$ pattern="Z"
$ k=3
$ a="foobar"
$ for ((i=0; i < $k; i++)); do a="${a:0:$i}$pattern${a:$((i+1))}"; echo $a; done
Zxxbar
ZZxbar
ZZZbar
$ echo $a
ZZZbar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
matStr=abc
repChar=y 
echo "${foo/$matStr/$(seq -s $repChar $((${#matStr}+1)) | tr -d '[0-9]')}"
```

This is not applicable when *repChar* is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

This would be fairly simple in Perl. I was looking for something similar in pure Unix utilities and BASH, but could think of any thing. The closest I found is `tr`.

This  written on Linux, so I use `sed -r`. If this is on Mac, It should be `sed -E`. In fact, you might even get away without using either the `-E` or `-r` flag i you use backslashes before the parentheses.

What I do is produce two strings with `sed`. The first finds the first `length` characters and tosses out the rest of the string. The second `sed` tosses out the first `length` characters and keeps the string. I can then use `tr` to replace all the characters with my replacement character, then concatenate the two strings together.

```
string="1234567890"
length="4"
replace="z"
prefix=$(sed -r -e "s/^(.{1,$length}).*/\1/" <<<"$string" | tr "[:alnum:]" "$replace")
postfix=$(sed -r -e "s/^.{1,$length}//" <<<"$string")
string="${prefix}${postfix}"
echo "$string"   #Will echo "zzzz567890"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy!

Variables:

```
str='helloworld'
k=3
char='.'
```

And the most important part:

Using Perl:

```
echo "$(perl -E "say '$char' x $k")${str:$k}"
```

Using Python:

```
echo "$(python -c "print '$char' * $k")${str:$k}"
```

Using printf and tr:

```
echo "$(printf "%${k}s" | tr ' ' "$char")${str:$k}"
```

Pure Bash:

```
for ((i = 0; i < $k; i++)); do echo -n "$char"; done
echo "${str:$k}"
```

Choose your weapon! I'd choose pure bash solution.