# how use position for replace a letter

Tags: bash, debian

code :

```
#!/bin/bash
word=$( sort -R $2 | head -1 | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
cache=$( echo $word | tr [A-Z] '_')
nb=$( echo $word | wc -m)
nbCar=$( echo $nb -1| bc)
echo "Mystery word: $cache ($nbCar letters)"
echo $word
echo "Enter a letter:"
read -n 1 letter
echo ""
pos=$( echo $word | grep -aob ${letter^^} | grep -oE '[0-9]+')
echo ${letter^^}
echo $pos
```

so how with my var `$pos` i can replace cache '_' by the letter read

example1: my word is `yoyo`

i read y

```
$pos = 0 2    
cache = y_y_
```

example2: my word is `yoyo`

i read a

```
$pos = NULL
cache = ____
```

echo "Not found"

Answer (score 1):

You could use two different approaches:

1. to read the string in the position you want

   echo ${word:$pos:1}

You'll echo one character from word in the position $pos

2. to write the string in the position you want

`echo $word | sed "s/./<The character that you want>/$pos"`

The " are important as you are putting a $pos (with only ' it would fail)

As you have multiple positions in your $pos, you'll have to iterate and change one at a time.

Interesting Links

- https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html
- [Change string char at index X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318021/change-string-char-at-index-x)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$letter` contains "y", `$cache` is already set to `"____"` and `pos` to `"0 2"`:

```
cache=$(echo $pos | tr ' ' '\n' |
        { while read pos
          do pos=$(expr $pos + 1)
          cache=$(echo $cache | sed -e 's/./'"$letter"'/'"$pos")
          done
          echo $cache
         })
```

Let's check the value:

```
$ echo $cache
y_y_
```

1. Here, tr replace the spaces of `$pos` whith a `end-of-line`
   character.
2. Then, the while loop process each values of `$pos`
3. For each value, it replaces the nth character of `$cache` by `$letter`.
4. At last, `$cache` is updated with the found letter.

[image: Screenshot as proof]

Curly brackets are here to put the while loop and the last echo in the same subshell, then this echo won't lose `$cache` value.

**Note:** I would say this method isn't the best, I'm calling `sed` for each replace. We could use Bash built-in functions/operators for that.

Comment: when i execute the code that write non-integer argument

Comment: i want modif only line i need with pos=$( echo $word | grep -aob ${letter^^} | grep -oE '[0-9]+')

Comment: i want to reshearch the pos in mtyvar word where the letter is                                    example :                                                                                                                    word=mama    i reshearch the pos of m in word it like a hangman

Comment: i think this is wrong grep -oE '[0-9]+') and i need fix it because with this command pos=$( echo $word | grep -aob ${letter^^} | grep -oE '[0-9]+') when i echo pos that write nothing

Answer (score 0):

The intention here seems to be to create a game where a random word is revealed by showing the positions of guessed letters.  The approach taken by the example code in the question is to start with a string of underscores and then replace underscores with guessed letters.  An easier approach is to replace unguessed letters with underscores.  This pure Bash code tries to implement the game:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -r wordsfile=$2

# Read the list of words into an array
mapfile -t words <"$wordsfile"

# Select a random word from the array, and uppercase it
myword=${words[RANDOM%${#words[*]}]^^}

# Set a variable to hold the word with unknown letters replaced by underscores
guessed_word=${myword//?/_}

printf 'Mystery word: %s (%d letters)\n' "$guessed_word" ${#myword}

guessed_letters=    # String containing letters guessed so far
while [[ $guessed_word != "$myword" ]] ; do
    printf 'Enter a letter:'
    read -r -n 1 letter
    printf '\n'

    guessed_letters+=${letter^}

    # Make a glob pattern that matches everything except letters that
    # have been guessed so far.  E.g. 'AB' -> '[^AB]'.
    other_letters_glob="[^$guessed_letters]"

    # Replace everything except guessed letters in the word with underscores
    guessed_word=${myword//$other_letters_glob/_}

    printf 'Mystery word: %s\n' "$guessed_word"
done
```

The code is Shellcheck-clean, but it has no error or input checking, and inadequate feedback even for a trivial game like this.

Comment: i just want to know how with grep take pos of the letter

Comment: i don't want a random word i want i word at line $3

Comment: @WilliamBROWAYS, I didn't use `grep` because I thought there was a better way to solve the real problem.  See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  Sorry if I was mistaken.

Comment: @WilliamBROWAYS, the code in the question (`sort -R $2 | head -1`) selects a random word from the file, and `$3` is not used or mentioned anywhere.  The code in this solution can easily be modified to meet the new requirement.  Just replace the `myword` assignment line with `myword=${words[$3-1]^^}` (assuming that $3 holds a line number with value 1 or higher).

Answer (score 0):

For "how with my var $pos i can replace cache '_' by the letter read" try:

```
for p in $pos ; do
    cache=${cache:0:p}${letter}${cache:p+1}
done
```

It seems from some comments that there may be problems creating the `pos` list.  This code should do it reliably:

```
pos=
for ((i=0; i<${#word}; i++)) ; do
    [[ ${word:i:1} == "$letter" ]] && pos+=" $i"
done
```

The `pos` value will have a leading space character if it is non-empty, but that shouldn't cause any problems.  It would be better to use an array for `pos`, but that would require changes elsewhere in the code.

Setting the `letter` in `cache` at the same positions as in `word` can be done without storing the positions at all:

```
ncache=
for ((i=0; i<${#word}; i++)) ; do
    [[ ${word:i:1} == "$letter" ]] && ncache+=$letter || ncache+=${cache:i:1}
done
cache=$ncache
```