# How to replace a character in a row based on the numbers in a column as the index of that character?

Tags: bash

I have the following file:

```
@0035e19a-bf41-43ee-b01e-f386c5d9969b  
TAGTATATTTTGTTTAGTTATGTTGGGTGGTGATTTTATGAGTTTTTGTTATTTATGAAA  
&$'&&%'&')-1:96)$$$'##&'%&2&&&:?9537=&&*&<6CC@@
2 0255 0 39 216 255 255  
3 0254 1 19 236 255 255  
7 0255 0 42 213 255 255  
10 0255 0 61 194 255 255  
15 0255 0 1 254 255 255
```

I want to replace letters in the second row with "C" based on the numbers in the first column after the 3rd row (2,3,7,10,15) as their index.
output like this:

```
@0035e19a-bf41-43ee-b01e-f386c5d9969b  
TCCTATCTTCTGTTCAGTTATGTTGGGTGGTGATTTTATGAGTTTTTGTTATTTATGAAA  
&$'&&%'&')-1:96)$$$'##&'%&2&&&:?9537=&&*&<6CC@@
2 0255 0 39 216 255 255  
3 0254 1 19 236 255 255  
7 0255 0 42 213 255 255  
10 0255 0 61 194 255 255  
15 0255 0 1 254 255 255
```

I know how to replace for example for one number as an index but as my table and second row are long it is not possible to do it one by one for each number as an index.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script with comments inside:

```
# input copied from your post
cat <<EOF >file
@0035e19a-bf41-43ee-b01e-f386c5d9969b  
TAGTATATTTTGTTTAGTTATGTTGGGTGGTGATTTTATGAGTTTTTGTTATTTATGAAA  
&$'&&%'&')-1:96)$$$'##&'%&2&&&:?9537=&&*&<6CC@@
2 0255 0 39 216 255 255  
3 0254 1 19 236 255 255  
7 0255 0 42 213 255 255  
10 0255 0 61 194 255 255  
15 0255 0 1 254 255 255  
EOF

# this will be a script executed with sed
sedscript=$(
    # get all lines except 3 first lines
    <file tail -n+4 |
    # extract first field
    cut -d' ' -f1 |
    # for each field
    # printf the command for sed
    # in the second line substitute 
    # any character at position for input
    # taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318021/change-string-char-at-index-x
    xargs printf "2s/./C/%d\n"
)

# execute the script on the file
sed -i "$sedscript" file

cat file
```

will output:

```
@0035e19a-bf41-43ee-b01e-f386c5d9969b  
TCCTATCTTCTGTTCAGTTATGTTGGGTGGTGATTTTATGAGTTTTTGTTATTTATGAAA  
&$'&&%'&')-1:96)152512$'##&'%&2&&&:?9537=&&*&<6CC@@
2 0255 0 39 216 255 255  
3 0254 1 19 236 255 255  
7 0255 0 42 213 255 255  
10 0255 0 61 194 255 255  
15 0255 0 1 254 255 255
```

Tested on [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/WNdVEV).

I create a sed script with the lines `2s/./C/<number>` which command in `sed` substitutes the characters for C in the second line at specified index. So for each index I create such line, and then such script is run with `sed`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kamil Cuk. It worked just fine

Comment: plus1 for reminding us that there is `/number` option apart from `/g` for sed regex search+replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ rec[NR] = $0 }
NR > 3 { rec[2] = substr(rec[2],1,$1-1) "C" substr(rec[2],$1+1) }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        print rec[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
@0035e19a-bf41-43ee-b01e-f386c5d9969b
TCCTATCTTCTGTTCAGTTATGTTGGGTGGTGATTTTATGAGTTTTTGTTATTTATGAAA
&$'&&%'&')-1:96)$$$'##&'%&2&&&:?9537=&&*&<6CC@@
2 0255 0 39 216 255 255
3 0254 1 19 236 255 255
7 0255 0 42 213 255 255
10 0255 0 61 194 255 255
15 0255 0 1 254 255 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using just bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a lines
lines=()

(
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [ "${line:0:1}" = "@" ]
    then
        for li in "${lines[@]}"
        do
            echo -e "$li"
        done
        unset lines
        lines=()

        lines+=("$line")    # @...
        IFS= read -r line
        lines+=("$line")    # TCA...
        IFS= read -r line
        lines+=("$line")    # &...
    else
        lines+=("$line")    # <num>...

        pos="${line/\ */}" #strip from first space to leave number
        bpos="$((pos-1))"
        # using acta as intermediary to not lose my head
        acta="${lines[1]}"
        acta="${acta:0:bpos}C${acta:$pos}" # substitute C
        lines[1]="$acta"
    fi
done < "$1"

for li in "${lines[@]}"
do
    echo -e "$li"
done
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Shell script composed of descriptive functions

Here's a solution with a shell script containing various functions with (hopefully) helpful names.

#### Usage

Assuming the file is save as `input.txt` and the shell script below is named `script.sh`, you will be able to generate the output by using:

```sh
$ .\script.sh input.txt
```

#### Actual Script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

read_file_input_output_var() {
    output_var="$(cat "$1")"
}

get_table() {
    tail -n +4 $1
}

get_first_column() {
    cut -d ' ' -f 1
}

replace_character_at_column() {
    sed_str="2s/./C/$1"
    sed $sed_str
}

replace_characters_in_output_var() {
    while read i
    do
        output_var="$(echo "$output_var" | replace_character_at_column $i)"
    done
}

print_result() {
    echo "$output_var"
}

main() {
    read_file_input_output_var $1

    get_table $1 |
    get_first_column |
    replace_characters_in_output_var

    print_result
}


main $1
```