# How to retrieve a character in a string at a index in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting I was wondering how do you index a string in bash
For example in C++ we would do string[0] to get the first character in the string, how to do a similar thing in shell scripting?

```
mystring=helloworld
```

I want to traverse the string character by character
For example in C++
I would do

```
for (auto i = 0;i < mystring.length(); i++)
      cout << mystring[i]
```

Comment: See [Change string char at index X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9318021/4154375) for ways to change the character at an index in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansion. `${#mystring}` returns the string length, `${mystring:offset:length}` returns a substring.

```
#! /bin/bash
mystring=helloworld
for ((i=0; i<${#mystring}; ++i)) ; do
    printf %s "${mystring:i:1}"
done
```

Comment: Can you please tell me If I want to change a character at a certain index on a string how can I do that? 
For example in C:
mystring[0] = 't';
How to do that in bash?

Comment: Strings are immutable; you can't modify them in-place.

Comment: @AbdullahChaudhry that would be `i=1 str=abc str="${str:0:i}X${str:i+1}"; echo "$str"`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Hello" | awk '{split($0,a,""); print a[1]}'
```

`print a[1]` This is for Index Character a[2] ... a[n] you can do

`{split($0,a,"")` This is for character to split `""` meaning split every character